# Include / ThenInclude in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have  DB Tables like that:

```
Continent -> Countries -> Cities
                       -> Lakes
```

Now i want to include them

```
_db.Continents
 .Include(p => p.Countries)
   .ThenInclude(c => c.Cities)
 .Include(p => p.Countries)
   .ThenInclude(p => p.Lakes)
```

Is this the only way (by including countries **twice**) or is there another way?

Comment: Look at the SQL generated - you only include `Countries` once.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way - by design. You are describing the include **paths**. Every path is included once. It's quite well explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes I did, just the syntax looks bit weird. I was wondering if there's another way.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks! If you put it as an answer i will mark it.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually support for this as of EF Core 2.1. The pattern looks something like this:

```
_db.Continents.Include(p => p.Countries).ThenInclude(c => c.Cities).ThenInclude((Country p) => p.Lakes)
```

Answer (score -2):

As said before EF Include countries only once.

for better reading you can write it like that :

```
_db.Continents
 .Include(p => p.Countries.Select(s => s.Cities))
 .ThenInclude(p => p.Countries.Select(s => s.Lakes))
```

Comment: Wrong answer. See the comment below the OP question.

Comment: Well Countries is a List<Country> and doesn't have a property Cities.

Comment: @OrcusZ that's EF 6 syntax. does that works also with EF core?

Comment: it does not work for EF Core 2.2, select statement should be replaced with ThenInclude